# setFragment cannot be applied to other fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fill out my FragmentReplacerActivity.java for my Android application but I've come across a few errors im confused about.

```
package com.example.soulforge;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.example.soulforge.fragments.CreateAccountFragment;
import com.example.soulforge.fragments.LoginFragment;

public class FragmentReplacerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_replacer);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        setFragment(new LoginFragment());

    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        if(fragment instanceof CreateAccountFragment ){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

[image: picture of the code with the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have imported '**androidx.fragment.app.Fragment**' in the **FragmentReplacerActivity** class. And check that it's imported correctly in your **LoginFragment**.

You might be missing the androidx fragment Gradle dependency in the **soulforge/app/build.gradle** file. It could be added the following way:

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    ...
}
```

Comment: I missed the import yes this was the issue thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

Check whether your LoginFragment class extends the Fragment class

**If this was not the case,**

Check if the LoginFragment class extends the correct Fragment class since there are multiple fragment classes

In your situation, check whether you extend

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

and not this

```
android.app.Fragment
```

**Or**

Check if the Fragment class in the setFragment method is same as that of the LoginFrgament extending Fragment class

Comment: My LoginFragment class extends Fragment like you said and ive checked the instanceof aswell but i still dont see the issue at the moment

Comment: I have edited my answer for an another cause of the error. Check now.